# Загрузочная флешка (USB) под линуксом (RFRemix)

Tags: linux, usb, boot, fedora, live-usb

Понимаю, вопрос обсуждался неоднократно. Но!

1) В последних версиях системы **UnetBootin** требует запуска под рутом, а под ним программа не работает, выдавая в консоли ошибки

2) **LiveUSB Creator** вроде как умер

3) **dd** В принципе это единственное, что работает, но усекает флешку до размера образа. Вкинуть другие файлы невозможно. Т.е. пользоваться потом флешкой для переноса/хранения невозможно.

Чем ещё можно воспользоваться?

Comment: И что мешает после `dd` запустить `fdisk` и создать ещё раздел на всё место до упора?

Comment: @0andriy не знание, что так можно сделать.

Comment: Ну не знаю. Gparted выводит информацию, что неправильно указан размер блока 512/4096
Создать раздел в свободном пространстве невозможно. Ошибка "Нельзя создавать больше двух первичных разделов"

Comment: Чисто для примера сейчас воткнул установочный образ Debian (на USB брелоке), `fdisk` замечательно работает: `/dev/sdc1  *  ...  290M
/dev/sdc2 ... 416K EFI (FAT-12/16/32) /dev/sdc3 ... 3.5G` (последний я только что добавил и даже перечитал обратно). У вас что-то неправильно изначально в образе или в том, как вы его записываете или в `gparted`.

Answer (score 3):

Grub2 давно умеет грузить образ диска напрямую. Т.е. достаточно установить на флешку grub2 (как это сделать полно статей в интернете) и указать ему какой образ диска загрузить.

Вот для начала вам статья: https://habrahabr.ru/post/135637/

Вот более подробные сведения: [https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB_(Русский)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9))

Преимущество данного метода в том, что загрузочная флешка не теряет своей функции и может использоваться параллельно для хранения и переноса своих файлов.

Пример:

```
sudo grub-install --no-floppy --root-directory=/media/my_flash /dev/sdb
```

Установит grub на устройство (флешку) /dev/sdb, которое смонтированно на /media/my_flash. В результате, в MBR будет прописан код загрузчика, а в корне устройства появится каталог boot.

Пример файла /boot/grub/grub.cfg:

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
insmod iso9660
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2F8F-02E9

menuentry " run runtu"{
    set iso_path="/boot/runtu-lite-14.04.1_20140914.iso"
    loopback loop ${iso_path}
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${iso_path}
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}

menuentry " run debian hd-media"{
    linux /boot/hdmedia/vmlinuz
    initrd /boot/hdmedia/initrd.gz
}
#EOF
```

Где "--set=root 2F8F-02E9" - uuid вашей флешки (узнать blkid).

Примера для RFR не покажу, но думаю при должном старании вы сами найдете.

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/202186)

Comment: @0xdb теперь развернутый

Comment: @alexanderbarakin готово

Answer (score 2):

В тегах Fedora:

```
~$ sudo dnf install mediawriter
```

Comment: mediawriter вылетает после нескольких секунд работы.
(Я так понял его нужно запускать под рутом)